# Toggle portlet columns in a Liferay Velocity template

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity

I am trying to create some sort of template which would show different portlets, according to a given parameter in the page, say for example a querystring or a request parameter.

I have the following code:

```
#if( $request.getParameter('sneiders') == 'snuffles' )
    <div class="col1" id="col1">$processor.processColumn("col1")</div>
#else
    <div class="col2" id="col2">$processor.processColumn("col2")</div>
#end
```

Portlets in column "col2" show up correctly, but portlets in column "col1", which should appear in /my/url?sneiders=snuffles, do not show up correctly. Somehow liferay just prints empty portlets, with the css class portlet-static

However, if i change things a little:

```
#if( $request.getParameter('sneiders') == 'snuffles' )
    <div class="col1" id="col1">$processor.processColumn("col1")</div>
#elseif( $request.getParameter('sneiders') == 'snuffzen')
    <div class="col2" id="col2">$processor.processColumn("col2")</div>
#else
    <div class="col1" id="col1">$processor.processColumn("col1")</div>
    <div class="col2" id="col2">$processor.processColumn("col2")</div>
#end
```

Portlets will show up correctly in any of those situations, which makes me think that you need a "default" case that will process all the columns

Has someone ran into this issue ? Is it an issue or am i doing things wrong ?

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you may need to setup your portlets in the layout while all the columns are shown, otherwise the layout won't save correctly. So when you place a portlet when only column-1 is shown, the portlets previously set up in column-2 will be gone.

You may consider doing something like this so you will be able to set up the layout correctly (yet users won't be able to mess with parameters to show both columns):

```
#if( $themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker().isOmniadmin() )
    <div class="col1" id="col1">$processor.processColumn("col1")</div>
    <div class="col2" id="col2">$processor.processColumn("col2")</div>
#elseif( $request.getParameter('sneiders') == 'snuffles' )
    <div class="col1" id="col1">$processor.processColumn("col1")</div>
#else
    <div class="col2" id="col2">$processor.processColumn("col2")</div>
#end
```

Comment: i know this thread is pretty old, but we just used this method and it worked out pretty well ! we used $themeDisplay.isSignedIn() instead